# Shell script in Linux: issues with commands after bash --rcfile option

Tags: python, linux, unix, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I've written a shell script that does several things, such as...

1. define environment variables
2. activates a python virtual environment

The issue I am having is any commands that I put in after the 2nd step does not get recognized.
I do this by the following line

```
bash --rcfile "<PATH_TO_VIR_ENV>/bin/activate" -i
```

The way I use my shell script is to first log in to the linux server then do

```
bash ./myScript.sh
```

This activates my virtual environment but doesn't do the things I would like it to do afterwards. For example source by .bashrc file so that I can use aliases stored in there.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: I think the way you are running creates a separate context, that is not applied to your current shell. Instead running `bash ./myScript.sh`, did you try something like `.  myScript.sh` or `source myScript.sh`?

Comment: I tried both '. ~/myScript.sh' and 'source ~/myScript.sh' but the results are the same. My aliases defined in my '.bashrc' file is not being picked up

Comment: _.bashrc_ is special. Some of the stuff must be in it and nowhere else (in your case you have to copy’n’paste into _activate_, which you declared to be the rc-file)